# Deploying python using CherryPy in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cherrypy

I am new to python. I have to run a python application from Amazon Cloud. I am using CherryPy and deploying through Beanstalk. Here is my simple HelloWorld code

```
import cherrypy

class Hello(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                            'server.socket_port': 80,})
    cherrypy.quickstart(Hello())
```

In `requirements.txt` file I have `CherryPy==10.2.2`. Still, I am not able to see any output in beanstalk URL. While deploying I get the following error,

> Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.

Can anyone give any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `WSGIPath` variable in *Software Configuration* specifies `application.py` as the init file. The `Hello` class in the above code was in a file named differently.

Make sure the initial code is in a file named `application.py` or change the configuration.